# Spring batch error - connection is read-only

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm having issue running Spring batch, the connection is read-only for some reason and I cannot figure out why. Here's the actual error -

```
Could not increment ID for BATCH_JOB_SEQ sequence table; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. 
Queries leading to data modification are not allowed.
```

I should point out that I had to extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer` because I've multiple data sources and transaction managers.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:765)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not increment ID for BATCH_JOB_SEQ sequence table; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.java:147)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:128)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
```

Here's my Batch configuration -

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(MyPersistenceJPAConfig.class)
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    public final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    public final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public BatchConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                            @Qualifier("myTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                            @Qualifier("myDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("myDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ");
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcPagingItemReader itemReader(PagingQueryProvider queryProvider) {

        Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();
        parameterValues.put("status", "ACTIVE");

        return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
            .name("myReader")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .queryProvider(queryProvider)
            .parameterValues(parameterValues)
            .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class))
            .pageSize(1000)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean queryProvider() {
        SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean provider = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();

        provider.setSelectClause("select id, first_name, last_name");
        provider.setFromClause("from person");
        provider.setWhereClause("where status=:status");
        provider.setSortKey("id");
        provider.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyProcessor processor() {
        return new MyProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer() {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job myJob(MyJobCompletionListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer, ItemReader<Person> itemReader) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
            .reader(itemReader)
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }
}
```

If I don't call `super(dataSource);` in the constructor, my job runs fine. There are no errors. This is because in the `DefaultBatchConfigurer.initialize()`, the dataSource is null and it switces to `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean`.

It is my understanding that we do not need to specify `@Transactional` while using Spring batch. I'm not sure what is that I am missing here, because of which the connection is read-only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your JPA config? This error simply means you've configured MySQL to read-only mode or you have provided slave nodes to the JPA, or it could also mean somewhere you have opened transaction in read-only mode.

Comment: You've rightly pointed out that in this case, the error is caused by the slave connection. I'm using an internal library that has both master and slave data sources configured. However, the crud operation from the service class using this data source is working correctly.

In my debug, I found that `void setReadOnly(boolean readOnly) ` of `java.sql.Connection` is called, which sets the read only to false when needed. This is not happening for batch.

For example, `CustomReadOnlyAwareHibernateJpaDialect` calls this to set read only to false, in which case master connection is returned.